# How to dynamically create dynamic componenets in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to know:

- How to create react components dynamically, for example from some simple objects.
- Can the dynamic creation works also in JSX?
- Does react offer a way to retrieve a component after has been created? For example by its id others meanings?

If you could provide me a minimalist working example I really appreciate it thanks!

```
    var data = [{
      type: 'button',
      props: {
        className: 'button button-blue',
        children: {
          type: 'b',
          props: {
            children: 'OK!'
          }
        }
      }
    },{
      type: 'button',
      props: {
        className: 'button button-blue',
        children: {
          type: 'b',
          props: {
            children: 'OK!'
          }
        }
      }
    }
];
```

Comment: why a downvote? please add a comment so I can improve my question

Comment: It wasn't from me, but I am guessing it's because you're asking for someone to write code for you, without explaining the intended use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made a nice list of things you don't do with React. The whole point of React is to declare how your component tree depends on the data and let the framework manage it for you. There's very few exceptional cases when you may want to do something hacky, though.

> How to create react components dynamically, for example from some
> simple objects.
>
> Can the dynamic creation works also in JSX?

You use React.createElement(). You have to use it once to initialize the framework. Other use cases I could think of is injecting things like modals into  or rendering into DOM generated by non-React library or component wrapped in a React component (basically a way to give control back to React). Unless you are doing one of those thing or really really know what you're trying to achieve, try to avoid this. For example, if you need a component that is sometimes rendered and sometimes not, use conditional rendering in your JSX, like this:

```
render() {
    return (
        <Something>
            <SomethingElse />
            {this.props.someProp ? <SomethingConditional /> : null}
        </Something>
    );
}
```

> Does react offer a way to retrieve a component after has been created? For example by its id others meanings?

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Again, try to use this only to inspect the DOM or do things that would be impossible or wasteful otherwise, like focus. Do not use it to modify DOM.